# How can i re calculate current scroll position to be in a certain range?

Tags: javascript

On scroll i want to re calculate the scroll position so it maps to another min and max value. If the scrollposition currently is 0, i want it to map to another value that should be 0.9, and when it has reached its final destination, eg when there is no more room to scroll i want it to map to 1.1. This is so i can use those values for certain css properties due runtime so it for example can change its `scaleX` dynamic. How would i do that?

```
document.addEventListener("scroll", (event) => {
  let lastscroll = window.scrollY;
});
```

markup

```
<div class="item1">dynamic content height</div>
<div class="item2">dynamic content height</div>
<div class="item3">dynamic content height</div>
```

Comment: What did you try? [Ask].

Comment: Not sure where to start really.